# Erlang store pool of mongodb connections

Tags: mongodb, erlang

How can i store pool of mongodb connections in erlang.

in one function i create pool of db connections

```
Replset = {<<"rs1">>, [{localhost, 27017}]},
Pool = resource_pool:new (mongo:rs_connect_factory (Replset), Count),
```

in second function i need to get connection from pool.

```
{ok, Conn} = resource_pool:get (Pool).
```

But i can not do this, because i created pool in another function.
I try to use records, but without success (

What i need to do to get it a bit global cross module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best solution is to use gen_server and store data in its state.
Another way is to use ets table.

Answer (score 1):

Some points to guide you in the correct direction:

- Erlang has no concept of a global variable. Bindings can only exist inside a process and that binding will be local to that process. Furthermore,
- Inside a process, there is no process-local bindings, only bindings which are local to the current *scope*.

Note that this is highly consistent with most functional programming styles.

To solve your problem, you need a process to keep track of your resource pool for you. Clients then call this process and asks for a resource. The resource manager can then handle, via, *monitors* what should happen should the client die when it has a checked out resource.

The easiest way to get started is to grab `devinus/poolboy` from Github and look into that piece of code.